# Formula for finding the initial velocity needed to launch a character a certain height in the air?

Tags: game-physics, physics

I'm trying to find a formula where when a character hits a bounce pad, the initial launch speed will be such that the peak of their jump will reach a specific height. The height and initial gravity are variable, and the time needed to reach the peak of the arc doesn't matter.

Comment: In a gravity field, the speed varies like v - gt and changes sign when v = gt. The height is given by vt - gt²/2, hence it peaks at h = gt² - gt²/2 = gt²/2. From this, t = √(2h/g) and v = √(2gh).

Comment: Note that @YvesDaoust gives the solution for the *vertical* component of velocity. The *horizontal* component can be whatever you like, it won't change the peak height. (Although it will affect the peak *location.)*